# If conditional in django template not reaching some branches

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I inherited a django 2.0 project at work and am trying to make what should be a simple change to a conditional in a template html file but cannot get it to reach the new branch.  I suspect a syntax issue but can't find it.

I have a bunch of rows some of which are rejected, some pending approval, some accepted.  This code is meant to display them appropriately:

```
<td class="vert-align blue-madison block">
    {% if row.is_rejected %}
        <span class="label label-sm label-danger">
            Rejected
        </span>
    {% elif not row.is_active %}
        <span class="label label-sm label-warning">
            Pending review
        </span>
    {% elif row.id|row_is_pending_deletion %}
        <span class="label label-sm label-danger">
            Pending deletion
        </span>
    {% else %}
        <span class="label label-sm label-success">
            Active
        </span>
    {% endif %}
</td>
```

four branches; Rejected, Pending Review, Pending Deletion, and Active.
Active and Pending Review work fine.  I haven't tested Pending Deletion.  Rejected is the new branch and I cannot get that to show up as it is above.

I know the most recent row has is rejected True as I have tested it in the django shell

```
>>> row.is_rejected
True
```

And I know that's the same row because I have looked to make sure the data in the row matches between the shell and the ui.

If I change the above code to be "{% if not row.is_rejected %}" then all the rows show up as Rejected with the appropriate red label, so the general syntax seems okay.

I checked the dbshell for the row and it shows is_rejected value of "t", is it possible that the code above isn't recognizing "t" as True?  I tried testing for both row.is_rejected == t and "t" in the first case all rows came back rejected and in the later I get the same result as my normal code above.

Comment: is_rejected was always a boolean field?

Comment: I'd guess so, but can't be strictly sure.  Is there a way to test or cope with if it wasn't?

Comment: The db is psql which I have minimal experience with but doesn't seem hugely different than mysql which I know a bit better.  On the other hand the "not row.is_active" portion seems to work just fine and that variable also stores "t" or "f"

Comment: Have you a filter or some manager returning just rows with `is_rejected` false?

Comment: What happens in the template when you print out the value? `{{ row.is_rejected }}`

Comment: That's actually exactly what I tried that led me to the solution below.  it printed nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a comment by Raydel Miranda above I managed to find the issue.  The template was not in fact referencing either the DB or the python object corresponding to the row in question.  Instead the views.py was handing off a rows dictionary which contained *partial* data for a row pulled from the python object (specifically the id and is_active fields.  I modified this to add the is_rejected field and now everything works.

My faith in the deterministic nature of the universe is restored.